# Windows server 2008 R2 backup - clear stale records

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup

I have been using Windows Server 2008 R2 backup.
I made several backup to a disk. Later I formated this disk and continued to make backups there. Thus, the backups made first turn to be stale, but It remains in the backup history.
How can I clear this records in the history?

Answer (score 4):

If I am understanding your question, these are stored in the Application log in Server Manager.

```
Open Event Logs -> Diagnostics -> Event Viewer -> Applications and Services -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Backup
```

The logs will need to be deleted from here

Comment: I only have logs going back to May 2012. But in Server Backup, the system is aware of backups going back to Apr 2010.  I don't think the info he is looking for is stored in this log.  I think he is looking for a way to clean up stale backup entires in the "Details of backups" option from the GUI.